# GameObject [] in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    for (int x = 0; x < mapLength; x++)
    {
        var instantiateMap = new Vector3(x * 2, 0, 1);
        GameObject[] cubeObjectClones = Instantiate(cubeObject, instantiateMap, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        cubeObjectClones[x].transform.parent = transform;
    }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to`UnityEngine.GameObject[]'

Can some explain how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method returns a single GameObject. Instead you need to use your loop to produce more instances and add them to your array. Use the code below.

```
GameObject[] cubeObjectClones = new GameObject[mapLength];
for (int x = 0; x < mapLength; x++)
{
    var instantiateMap = new Vector3(x * 2, 0, 1);
    cubeObjectClones[x] = Instantiate(cubeObject, instantiateMap, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    cubeObjectClones[x].transform.parent = transform;
}
```